# How to generate setters and getters in Visual Studio Code for Powershell?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, ide

(How) can one automatically generate `getters` and `setters` of object fields/variables after having created the fields/variables in an object, when working with IDE Visual Studio Code (version 1.37.1+) in a `<filename>.ps1` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are looking for doesn't currently exist.

VSCode cannot do this natively, and you have probably already installed the Powershell extension, which also doesn't support this.

I haven't check all the extensions, but your best bet is to wait that someone creates such an extension.

Comment: for your clarification, thank you very much. Indeed I also installed the Powershell extension. As for your recommendation, I think active participation/contribution to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute could be a better bet.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, that would be a good way to get started. I would imagine that creating such an extension isn't very hard, but who knows.